# PowerPoint Add-in directly access its object

Tags: vba, c#-4.0, add-in, powerpoint

Powerpoint file is actually a zip file that contains xml sub-files. These sub-files illustrate all the properties of objects of every slides (e.g., position, color, animation, etc.). You can convert the pptx file into zip file and unzip it you will see sub xml files.

Now, I want to create a Powerpoint Add-in application, allowing me to add more information to a specific object, and store dynamically it in itself XML file (or when saving file as). For example, my Add-in PowerPoint application contains a button named "Flippable". When I select a specific object of a slide, and select "Flippable", my application will find the xml file that contains the object information, and add a tag "Flippable = true".

Is it possible to do that dynamically when running application?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why go to all the effort of cracking and parsing the XML file, assuming that you even *can* while he presentation's open in PPT, especially since you're already doing this from an add-in?

You mentioned that the user has selected a shape.  Why not just tag the shape:

```
With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
  .Tags.Add "Flippable", "Yes"
End With
```

You'd want a bit more code around that to make sure that there IS a selection, and if you want to allow tagging multiple shapes at one time, you'd need to put in inside a For Each/Next loop.

Then assuming a reference to the current shape to be tested in oSh

```
If oSh.Tags("Flippable")="Yes" Then
   ' Do your stuff
End If
```

Comment: it's not correct. The result is the tag "Flippable" and "True" will be stored in a separate file name "Tags.xml". Information of the slide will be stored in another file named for example "slide1.xml". And there is no relationship between the tag "flippable" and a given object in the "slide1.xml"

Comment: Sorry.  You're wrong, and you obviously haven't even bothered to try it.  I won't bother you with any further suggestions.

Comment: what do you mean @Steve? It means that there is no way to embed extra information into xml file of Powerpoint?

Comment: You said that there is no relationship between the tag and the object to which it's applied.  That's simply not correct, because the tag information can be retrieved from the object at any time later.  The relationship is there whether it's apparent to you or not. If you MUST work with the XML instead of simply applying/retrieving the tags in PPT directly, then you'll have to work out how the information is related.  Or work out how to add the info to the xml in some other way.

Comment: If you try it, you'll find that tags applied in this way do appear in the XML. And if you need to modify the XML directly, doing it this way first will produce working examples of how to go about it.

Comment: I agree that the tags are stored in a folder in the XML presentation structure. However, I don't see any relationship between tags and objects in slides. I see your point here that there must be relationships between them. I created the link between them by adding the ID of object, and ID of slide into the tags

Comment: Add a tag using the code I showed you above.  Add it to the presentation object, slide objects, shape objects, it doesn't matter.  Then save the presentation and look at the XML.  If you don't believe that there's a relationship after that, there's not much more I can suggest.

Comment: Ok, thanks @SteveRindsberg. Tags as you suggested is very useful. Now, the extra information I want to embed into pptx file is not just a simple value such as: tags.add("Flippable","True"). Is it possible to embed a image file, a text file into pptx file? How can I do that. With tags, I don't think I can.

Comment: You can embed pretty much however much text as you like as tags (text, tags are strings).  There are also binary tags which'd allow for images, but I've never used them so can't give any direct advice.  Also, you *can* add random files into the ZIP package but you must also include the correct pointers in, I think, the rels file, otherwise PowerPoint will assume the file's corrupt and refuse to open it.